# Updating complex rails app, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Did some version bumps in Gemfile, even used special site RailsBumb, but still get long error message like:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actioncable":
  In Gemfile:
    action-cable-testing was resolved to 0.6.1, which depends on
      actioncable (>= 5.0)

    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      actioncable (= 6.1.6)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.13) was resolved to 0.10.13, which depends on
      actionpack (< 7.1, >= 4.1)

    activerecord-session_store (>= 1.1.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.2.4.1)

    inherited_resources was resolved to 1.13.1, which depends on
      actionpack (< 7.1, >= 5.2)

    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 6.1.6)

    rails-controller-testing was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.rc1)

    inherited_resources was resolved to 1.13.1, which depends on
      responders (< 4, >= 2) was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 5.0)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.2)

    slim-rails (~> 3.5.1) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionview":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      actionview (= 6.1.6)

    rails-controller-testing was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.rc1)

    web-console (>= 2.1.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.13) was resolved to 0.10.13, which depends on
      activemodel (< 7.1, >= 4.1)

    paperclip (~> 6.1) was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      activemodel (= 6.1.6)

    simple_form was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.2)

    validate_url was resolved to 1.0.15, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

    web-console (>= 2.1.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-nulldb-adapter (~> 0.8.0) was resolved to 0.8.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 7.1, >= 5.2.0)

    activerecord-postgis-adapter (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.1, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 6.1)

    activerecord-session_store (>= 1.1.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 5.2.4.1)

    annotate (~> 2.7.5) was resolved to 2.7.5, which depends on
      activerecord (< 7.0, >= 3.2)

    awesome_nested_set (~> 3.4.0) was resolved to 3.4.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 7.0, >= 4.0.0)

    delayed_job_active_record (>= 4.1.5) was resolved to 4.1.7, which depends on
      activerecord (< 8.0, >= 3.0)

    jsonapi-resources was resolved to 0.11.0.beta1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 5.1)

    paranoia (~> 2.2) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 7.1, >= 5.1)

    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      activerecord (= 6.1.6)

    activerecord-postgis-adapter (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.1, which depends on
      rgeo-activerecord (~> 7.0.0) was resolved to 7.0.1, which depends on
        activerecord (>= 5.0)

    scoped_search (~> 4.1) was resolved to 4.1.10, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.2.0)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    delayed_job (>= 4.1.10) was resolved to 4.1.10, which depends on
      activesupport (< 8.0, >= 3.0)

    factory_bot_rails was resolved to 6.2.0, which depends on
      factory_bot (~> 6.2.0) was resolved to 6.2.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 5.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 6.1) was resolved to 6.1.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 6.1.6)

    rails-controller-testing was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.rc1)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 5.2)

    wicked_pdf (~> 1.1) was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
      activesupport
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "listen":
  In Gemfile:
    listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)

    spring-watcher-listen (>= 2.0.1) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
      listen (< 4.0, >= 2.7)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "omniauth":
  In Gemfile:
    omniauth (~> 1.0.3)

    omniauth-vkontakte was resolved to 1.8.0, which depends on
      omniauth-oauth2 (>= 1.5, <= 1.8.0) was resolved to 1.5.0, which depends on
        omniauth (~> 1.2)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 6.1.6)

    paperclip-watermark was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      rails

    rails-jquery-autocomplete (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.0.5, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.2)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-session_store (>= 1.1.1) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.2.4.1)

    dotenv-rails was resolved to 2.7.6, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2)

    factory_bot_rails was resolved to 6.2.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.0.0)

    inherited_resources was resolved to 1.13.1, which depends on
      railties (< 7.1, >= 5.2)

    jquery-rails (~> 4.3) was resolved to 4.5.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0)

    jquery-ui-rails (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2.16)

    jsonapi-resources was resolved to 0.11.0.beta1, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.1)

    rails (= 6.1.6) was resolved to 6.1.6, which depends on
      railties (= 6.1.6)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 5.2)

    sass-rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.1, ~> 2.1) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.0)

    slim-rails (~> 3.5.1) was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1)

    web-console (>= 2.1.0) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
```

Tried dozens combinations of versions, but still this kind of error,
It looks like dead end, any ideas ?

Here is Gemfile

```
diff --git a/Gemfile b/Gemfile
index 638cd59..a973528 100644
--- a/Gemfile
+++ b/Gemfile
@@ -1,18 +1,20 @@
 source 'https://rubygems.org'
 
+ruby "2.7.6"
+
 git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
   repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
 end
-gem 'tzinfo-data'
 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
-gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
+gem 'rails', '6.1.6'
+gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 #gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4'
 # Use Puma as the app server
-gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
+gem 'puma', '~> 5.6.4'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
-gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
+gem 'sass-rails', '~> 6.0.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
@@ -22,10 +24,10 @@ gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 gem 'turbolinks'
 
 #redis
-gem 'redis', '~> 3.2'
+gem 'redis', '~> 4.7'
 
 #OmniAuth
-gem 'omniauth'
+gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.0.3'
 gem 'omniauth-facebook'
 gem 'omniauth-vkontakte', github: 'mamantoha/omniauth-vkontakte'
 gem 'omniauth-mail_ru'
@@ -35,13 +37,15 @@ gem 'omniauth-odnoklassniki'
 gem "omniauth-yandex"
 gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'
 
+gem 'actionpack', '6.1.6'
+
 group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   gem 'pry-rails'
   # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
-  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
-  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
+  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7.1'
+  gem 'selenium-webdriver'  
   gem 'dotenv-rails'
   gem 'rails-controller-testing'
   gem 'action-cable-testing'
@@ -49,11 +53,11 @@ end
 
 group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
-  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
+  gem 'web-console', '>= 2.1.0'
   gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
-  gem 'spring'
-  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
+  gem 'spring', '< 3.0'
+  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '>= 2.0.1'
 end
 
 group :test do
@@ -70,7 +74,7 @@ gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
 gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1'
 
 # SLIM templates
-gem 'slim-rails', '~> 3.1'
+gem 'slim-rails', '~> 3.5.1'
 
 # Admin forms
 gem 'simple_form'
@@ -79,8 +83,8 @@ gem 'inherited_resources'
 gem 'validate_url'
 
 # fixutres
-gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.8'
-gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.6'
+gem 'factory_bot_rails'
+gem 'database_cleaner', '<= 2.0.0.beta'
 
 # TODO: remove this gem
 # переменные окружения в application.yml
@@ -94,31 +98,31 @@ gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12'
 # яндекс касса
 gem 'yandex-money-sdk', '~> 1.0'
 # хранение сессии в БД
-gem 'activerecord-session_store', '~> 1.1'
+gem 'activerecord-session_store', '>= 1.1.1'
 
 # delayed_job
-gem 'delayed_job', '~> 4.1'
-gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.1'
+gem 'delayed_job', '>= 4.1.10'
+gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '>= 4.1.5'
 gem 'daemons', '~> 1.2'
 
 # локализация
-gem 'i18n', '~> 0.9'
+gem 'i18n', '~> 1.10.0'
 gem 'russian', '~> 0.6'
-
+  
 # Image upload
-gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
+gem 'paperclip', '~> 6.1'
 gem 'paperclip-watermark', :github => 'vikewoods/paperclip-watermark'
 
 # JSON API
 gem 'jsonapi-resources', github: 'cerebris/jsonapi-resources'
 
 # Annotate models
-gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7', require: false
+gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7.5', require: false
 
 gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.0'
 gem 'rack-cors', '~> 1.0'
 
-gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10'
+gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.13'
 gem 'scoped_search', '~> 4.1'
 
 # JavaScript libraries - remove after fully migrated to angular
@@ -134,18 +138,18 @@ gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1'
 gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0'
 
 # needed to compile assets without database
-gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter', '~> 0.3'
+gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter', '~> 0.8.0'
 # Localities tree structure
-gem 'awesome_nested_set', '~> 3.1'
+gem 'awesome_nested_set', '~> 3.4.0'
 
 gem 'rgeo'
 gem 'rgeo-proj4'
 gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4'
-gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '~> 5.2.3'
+gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '~> 7.0.0'
 gem 'savon', '~> 2.12.0'
 gem 'faraday'
 # Authorization
-gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.0'
+gem 'cancancan', '~> 3.4.0'
 
 # deploy
 gem 'mina'
```

Comment: What was your previous Ruby on Rails and what version do you want to update to? Please also share your `Gemfile`.

Comment: from 5.1 to 6.1, Gemfile attached

Comment: The biggest problem I see with your Gemfile is that there are many gems pinned to specific versions. That makes it hard or impossible for bundler to find a match combination. I would suggest updating the smaller gems to the latest available version first by removing the version number from a gem in the Gemfile and then running `bunde update` for that gem and fixing all issues. Once that is done the big rails update should be much easier.

Comment: "Tried dozens combinations of versions" - there is no need to manually adjust dozens of version combinations, that's a sign that your Gemfile is overly(or unnecessarily) restricted. Try to lessen some of those restrictions first, especially github origins

Comment: "change rails to 6.1.6, remove versions from i18n and activerecord-postgis-adapter" - still get long error message about dependencies

Comment: ". I would suggest updating the smaller gems to the latest available version first by removing the version number from a gem in the Gemfile and then running bunde update" this doesn't give error anymore but looks like bundle update frozen with message "Resolving dependencies...."

Comment: well, I can only work with what you have posted. can you just post your entire Gemfile for rails 5.1.3.